# save the last part of url in variable

Tags: php, url

I want to get the last part of an url that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/blog/public/index.php/categories/Horror
```

I've tried it with

```
$endOfUrl = end(explode('/',$url));
```

but the thing is I get a notice that "Only variables should be passed by reference"

I need this "Horror" to get it's ID in my database and get all the posts with this id, since I'm trying to code a blog to get experience with php.

Another question linked to this: Is it possible to make it dynamic so it can be used for all the other categories as well? Or do I have to do this for every single category?

I'm new to the world of php so I would really appreciate it if someone could help me on this.

Comment: and yes, I need it saved in a variable

Comment: can we see how $url is declared?

Answer (score 3):

Try like this way for `end()` but If I were you I will try `basename()` to get my job done.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost:8888/blog/public/index.php/categories/Horror';
$exploded = explode('/',$url);
$endOfUrl = end($exploded);
echo $endOfUrl;
?>
```

**Reason why it is not working on single line:**

> end() requires a reference, because it modifies the internal
>   representation of the array (i.e. it makes the current element pointer
>   point to the last element).The result of explode('.', $url) cannot be
>   turned into a reference and this is a restriction in the PHP language itself.

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/ttKui

Using `basename()`,

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8888/blog/public/index.php/categories/Horror';
echo basename($url);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/pt2cQ

Comment: upvote for edited answer - the reason why segment clears it up a lot :)

Comment: Well thank you for the fast answer and the explanation, it worked.

Comment: @treyBake thankz for voting it up mate, I've edited again by giving suggestion to use `basename()`

Comment: but is there a way to make it automatically work with something else than "Horror"?  or do I really have to make different functions/ ifelses for each category?

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon have you checked my edit again, I used `basename()`

Comment: I did, but the url now is declared as "horror" at the end, but what if the url is like '...categories/Fantasy'?

Comment: check my demo here https://3v4l.org/G8h3j I don't see any problem with that

Comment: I mean the url itself, not the variable $url.